# Error while installing opencv-contrib-python 3.3.0.9

Tags: python, opencv, pip, pycharm

I am trying to install `opencv-contrib-python 3.3.0.9` using command `python -m pip install opencv-contrib-python==3.3.0.9`.

However it is throwing the following error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-contrib-python==3.3.0.9 (from versions: 3.4.2.16, 3.4.2.17, 3.4.3.18, 3.4.4.19, 3.4.5.20, 3.4.6.27, 3.4.7.28, 3.4.8.29, 4.0.0.21, 4.0.1.23, 4.0.1.24, 4.
1.0.25, 4.1.1.26, 4.1.2.30)
No matching distribution found for opencv-contrib-python==3.3.0.9
```

I am using Python 3.7, opencv 4.1.2.30 and PyCharm.

Answer (score 1):

Can you install a newer version of `opencv-contrib-python` by using 

`pip install opencv-contrib-python`?

According to https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/3.3.0.9/, that version does not support Python 3.7 and it also provides a link to the [latest version](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/) which mention support Python 3.7 and installation guide (i.e. `pip install opencv-contrib-python`)